# Trigger a CI stage automatically after a merge request was merged

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have defined a clean-up stage in Gitlab CI scipt that is used to automatically shut down the instance after the branch's testing, and I would like to have this stage being automatically triggered once I merged this branch into the master through the merge request in Gitlab, how should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the merge goes into develop you could use
cleanup:
stage: cleanup
only:
- develop
That way it'd be trigger by the merge rather than the merge request.
Anyhow, I'd say that what you aim to do should be done directly in the same pipeline and not wait until it is merged though